# Make file to compile two C program files

Tags: linux, unix, makefile, g++

I have two C program files named client.c and server.c. Both of these contains main function. I am having trouble in compiling them using g++ with makefile.

```
all:
    g++ client.c server.c -o client server.c
```

Comment: You need to make two compile targets one for each program.. What you have now will try and build a single output binary called "client" that merges the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out since these are the two different files so they should be compiled separately like this.

```
all: client server

client:
       g++ -o client client.c

server:
       g++ -o server server.c
```